# Trimmed attachment in e-mail

Tags: python-2.7, email, smtp, base64, attachment

I send e-mail attachment via python function. Everything okay except on thing, my attach is trimmed. There is trimmed around 200 strings and I can't understand where loose them. I checked my function in debugger and found that before `encoders.encode_base64(part)` `part.set_payload` is same size as file size on HDD, but in result I receive trimmed attachment.

Send mail function below:

```
def mail_sender(recipients, sender, z_name, z_count=0):
    for recipient in recipients:
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        sender = '%s' % sender
        subject = "report on %s" % (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
        body = "Good morning, enjoy todays report.\n\nTotal: %d" % z_count

        msg['From'] = sender
        msg['To'] = recipient
        msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        part = MIMEBase('application', "base64")
        part.set_payload(open("result.txt", "rb").read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="result.txt"')
        msg.attach(part)

        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
        s.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why attach was trimmed. I forget to close file handler before executing my send mail function.